# React: ReactTransitionGroup hidden element not reappearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with `ReactTransitionGroup`, whereby an element which has just had `.superfade-leave-active` applied, doesn't apply `.superfade-enter` afterwards, when the render method is telling it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/joecritch/6bpJD/3/

The logic is that the message shown is the first item in the `ReactTransitionGroup` list, and my `UserSearchResults` component is the second. The latter only appears when the data is loaded. (The data is mocked as an array at the top, and is loaded with a 500ms delay.)

**Desired result:** first element appears whenever there is text in the list; second always appears whenever the data is loaded

**Actual result:** first element works as desired; second shows initially, but then after any text change after 500ms, it animates away.

**Note:** When the animate component is removed, it works as expected.

Comment: Forgot to save your jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Here is the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/joecritch/6bpJD/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you ran into a bug in React that was fixed a few weeks ago but didn't make it into the latest release:

https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/c313a1045db0a81a704df14f5da60f3690441fbf

If I change your jsfiddle to use a nightly build of react (http://react.zpao.com/builds/master/latest/react-with-addons.js) then it appears to me to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks man, I can confirm that works. I'll keep testing between stable and nightly in any future cases.